# Unable to connect USB devices to NComputing device except keyboard/mouse

Tags: 16.04, printing, scanner, usb-installation

As I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my PC, NComputing device is connected to the PC and I'm unable to connect any Scanner or Printer directly to NComputing device. Kindly provide any valuable and appropriate solution on it.

Comment: "I'm unable to connect any Scanner or Printer directly to NComputing device" ....... I am guessing that means that if you plug a printer in to a usb port, on the NComputing that `lsusb` shows no results? which printer and scanner have you tried please?

Comment: As I have tried with multiple devices to connect to NComputing such as Fujitsu 1120 Scanner, PANDIGITAL S81100 Scanner, Avision 110 Scanner, HP LaserJet 1020plus, Brother HL2321 printer etc.

Comment: so if any of these are usb devices; if you type `lsusb` in a terminal; with one of them connected; does the device get seen please?

Comment: No, it shows nothing after check with lsusb command in terminal.

Comment: that sort of suggests a hardware issue; that the computer is not "seeing" these things